# Gitlab Static Application Security Testing (SAST) fails with permission denied

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to add Static Application Security Testing (SAST) to my ci/cd yaml file.
But when I run it after adding the template `Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml` as instructed in

it fails with this log

```
[ERRO] [Find Security Bugs] [2022-01-06T13:20:34Z] ▶ Project couldn't be built: Command couldn't be executed: fork/exec /builds/Hoshani/my-awesome-project/mvnw: permission denied

[FATA] [Find Security Bugs] [2022-01-06T13:20:34Z] ▶ Command couldn't be executed: fork/exec /builds/Hoshani/my-awesome-project/mvnw: permission denied
```

here is the yaml file for your reference

```yaml
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"

image: maven:3.8.1

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

stages:          
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:       
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean install

include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/SAST-IaC.latest.gitlab-ci.yml

unit-test-job:   
  stage: test    
  script:
    - mvn test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution, simply adding execution permission on **mvnw** will fix this.

```
chmod a+x mvnw
```

For more details, refer [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/218342#possible-fixes)